# Scraping Amazon Brand Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

For training purposes, trying to scrape prices of the following page

https://www.amazon.fr/s?i=watches&bbn=60649031&rh=n%3A60649031%2Cp_89%3AICE-Watch&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584806397&rnid=1680780031&ref=sr_pg_1

Using Puppeteer, here is the part of selector code inside evaluate:

```
        const result = await page.evaluate(() =>{
        return [...document.querySelectorAll('.sg-col-inner')].map(o => {
            return {
              brand: o.querySelector('.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base').innerText,
              title: o.querySelector('.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal').innerText,
              price: o.querySelector('.a-price-whole').innerText,
              url: o.querySelector('.a-link-normal.a-text-normal').href,
            };
          });
      });
```

brand, title, and url are working properly and return data, while price remains undefined.

Error message:

```
error happened Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that:

1. Not all `'.sg-col-inner'` elements are valid, maybe `'.s-result-list.s-search-results .sg-col-inner'` is better  selector.
2. Not all elements have prices in the links. Maybe something like this selector is better: `'.a-price-whole, br + .a-color-base'`.

Example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://www.amazon.fr/s?i=watches&bbn=60649031&rh=n%3A60649031%2Cp_89%3AICE-Watch&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584806397&rnid=1680780031&ref=sr_pg_1');

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll('.s-result-list.s-search-results .sg-col-inner')].map(o => {
        return {
          brand: o.querySelector('.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base').innerText,
          title: o.querySelector('.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal').innerText,
          price: o.querySelector('.a-price-whole, br + .a-color-base').innerText,
          url: o.querySelector('.a-link-normal.a-text-normal').href,
        };
      });
    });

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Steel Montre Homme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone IC017325',
    price: '132,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-IC017325/dp/B081S1WZRM/ref=sr_1_1?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-1'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'IC016982 Montre à Bracelet pour Femme Neuve et Original',
    price: '95,95',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Watch-IC016982-Montre-Bracelet-Original/dp/B07VRZF1P8/ref=sr_1_2?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-2'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Flower Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone IC016665',
    price: '95,95',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Flower-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-IC016665/dp/B07NYZBT3Q/ref=sr_1_3?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-3'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Steel Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Acier Inoxydable IC017321',
    price: '165,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Inoxydable-IC017321/dp/B081S2LV53/ref=sr_1_4?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-4'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Steel Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Acier Inoxydable IC017319',
    price: '165,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Inoxydable-IC017319/dp/B081S2K22C/ref=sr_1_5?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-5'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Steel Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Acier Inoxydable IC017322',
    price: '165,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Inoxydable-IC017322/dp/B081S1P3SX/ref=sr_1_6?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-6'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Change Montre Mixte Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone IC016052',
    price: '86,95',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Change-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-IC016052/dp/B081RYZM94/ref=sr_1_7?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-7'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Tintin Montre Mixte Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone IC015306',
    price: '99,00',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Tintin-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-IC015306/dp/B07VSGY8JG/ref=sr_1_8?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-8'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice-Glam Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC017057',
    price: '99,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Glam-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC017057/dp/B07VS1Z8KX/ref=sr_1_9?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-9'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Duo Chic Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC016979',
    price: '110,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC016979/dp/B07VRYBQHH/ref=sr_1_10?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-10'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Duo Chic Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC016985',
    price: '110,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC016985/dp/B07VPV5P56/ref=sr_1_11?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-11'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'IC017058 Montre à Bracelet pour Femme Neuve et Original',
    price: '134,90',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Watch-IC017058-Montre-Bracelet-Original/dp/B07VPSLVXH/ref=sr_1_12?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-12'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'IC016984 Montre à Bracelet pour Femme Neuve et Original',
    price: '99,00',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Watch-IC016984-Montre-Bracelet-Original/dp/B07VLM2L85/ref=sr_1_13?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-13'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice lo Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC015606',
    price: '99,00',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC015606/dp/B07TJZ3XMW/ref=sr_1_14?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-14'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice lo Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC016904',
    price: '110,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC016904/dp/B07TJXDKGD/ref=sr_1_15?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-15'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'ICE Watch Watch IC016769 Femmes Argent/Acier Gris',
    price: '162,40',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Watch-IC016769-Femmes-Argent-Acier/dp/B07SXRLHPC/ref=sr_1_16?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-16'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'ICE Watch IC016763 Montre Unisexe Or Rose Acier',
    price: '164,60',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Watch-IC016763-Montre-Unisexe-Acier/dp/B07SXR4WHX/ref=sr_1_17?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-17'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'ICE Watch Watch IC016777 Femmes Or Acier',
    price: '146,80',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/ICE-Watch-IC016777-Femmes-Acier/dp/B07STJ7FDZ/ref=sr_1_18?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-18'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice lo Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC015604',
    price: '95,95',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC015604/dp/B07STF8T72/ref=sr_1_19?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-19'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'ICE Watch IC016771 Montre en Silicone Argent/Gris pour Homme',
    price: '116,90',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Watch-IC016771-Montre-Silicone-Argent/dp/B07SSH93YX/ref=sr_1_20?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-20'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'ICE Watch Watch IC016891 Femmes Argent/Acier Gris',
    price: '144,60',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Watch-IC016891-Femmes-Argent-Acier/dp/B07SRGQGVV/ref=sr_1_21?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-21'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice lo Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC015605',
    price: '99,00',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC015605/dp/B07SRCM67N/ref=sr_1_22?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-22'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice lo Montre Femme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Caoutchouc IC013990',
    price: '97,94',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Caoutchouc-IC013990/dp/B07SQ9JLSV/ref=sr_1_23?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-23'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'ICE Watch IC016761 Montre Unisexe Or Acier',
    price: '163,50',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Watch-IC016761-Montre-Unisexe-Acier/dp/B07RL3DD8Q/ref=sr_1_24?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-24'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice-Sunshine - Sun.NYW.S.S.13 : Montre Mixte Résine & Silicone - Mouvement Quartz - Cadran Jaune',
    price: '46,46',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Watch-Ice-Sunshine-Sun-NYW-S-S-13-Silicone-Mouvement/dp/B07QR42J5M/ref=sr_1_25?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-25'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Urban Montre Homme Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone IC016307',
    price: '143,00 €',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-IC016307/dp/B07PQ7FWFM/ref=sr_1_26?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-26'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: '015765 Montre Femme',
    price: '82,28',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Watch-015765-Montre-Pastel-Femme/dp/B07NJRMCF7/ref=sr_1_27?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-27'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: '015761 Montre Femme',
    price: '82,28',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Watch-015761-Montre-Femme-Pastel/dp/B07NJRCBL2/ref=sr_1_28?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-28'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: '015758 Montre Femme',
    price: '82,28',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Watch-015758-Montre-Pastel-Femme/dp/B07NJR6Q7S/ref=sr_1_29?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-29'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Ola Montre Mixte Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone Ice.PE.U.S.15',
    price: '79,00',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Montre-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-Ice-PE-U-S-15/dp/B07NF47C47/ref=sr_1_30?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-30'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Watch Loveheart Montre analogique',
    price: '50,40',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/ICE-Watch-Montre-013730/dp/B074N8LD1R/ref=sr_1_31?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-31'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice Safari Montre Mixte Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone SP.Ice.CHA.U.S.15',
    price: '89,00',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Safari-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-SP-Ice-CHA-U-S-15/dp/B017DGW3VW/ref=sr_1_32?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-32'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Ice-Chocolate Montre Mixte Analogique Quartz avec Bracelet Silicone CT.CA.U.S.10',
    price: '89,95',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Ice-Chocolate-Analogique-Bracelet-Silicone-CT-CA-U-S-10/dp/B00CFP0M5Q/ref=sr_1_33?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-33'
  },
  {
    brand: 'ICE-Watch',
    title: 'Stone Multifunction Montre Femme Unisexe MF. WS. U.S.10, Bracelet Plastique, Analogique, Quartz, 5 Bar, Verre minéral One Size, Blanc, Blanc',
    price: '159,90',
    url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Multifunction-unisexe-Bracelet-Plastique-Analogique/dp/B004N4Z9UA/ref=sr_1_34?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584870152&refinements=p_89%3AICE-Watch&rnid=1680780031&s=watch&sr=1-34'
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide any info about the error? I've added a code example and its result, it works for me.

Comment: Beware though some prices are ended in `' €'`.

Answer (score 2):

Import necessary libraries such as Nokogiri for HTML parsing and URI, Net/HTTP, and OpenSSL for handling URLs and making HTTP requests.
Define the URL to scrape and parse it using URI.
Create a hash containing various HTTP headers required for the request, such as 'Accept', 'Accept-Language', and 'User-Agent'
Send an HTTP GET request to the specified URL using the configured connection and headers.
Check if the response is successful
If successful, proceed to parse the HTML content of the response using Nokogiri.

Using XPath, locate specific elements in the HTML document that contain the desired data
output the extracted data to the console or perform further processing as needed.

Code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

url = 'https://www.amazon.fr/s?i=watches&bbn=60649031&rh=n%3A60649031%2Cp_89%3AICE-Watch&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584806397&rnid=1680780031&ref=sr_pg_1'
uri = URI.parse(url)

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = uri.scheme == 'https'
http.open_timeout = 40
http.read_timeout = 40

headers = {
  'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'Accept-Language' => 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'
}


begin
  data_array = []
  response = http.get(uri.request_uri, headers)
  if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
    data_hash = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'s-card-container')]")
    if not data_hash or data_hash.to_s.empty?
      $log.error "Not able to find products in page url: #{url}"
      return []
    end
    data_hash and data_hash.each do |item|
      data = {}
      next if not item
      title = item.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'a-text-normal')]").first
      brand = item.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'s-title')]//text()").first
      price = item.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'a-price')]//span[contains(@class,'a-price-whole')]").first
      data["title"] = title.content if title
      data["brand"] = brand.content if brand
      data["price"] = price.content.to_f if price
      data_array << data
    end
    puts data_array
  else
    puts "HTTP request failed with status code #{response.code}"
  end
rescue Exception => e
  puts "An error occurred: #{e.message}"
end
```

**Output**

```
{  "title"=>"Smart Watch 022251", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>68.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Smart - Montre Connectée pour Enfant avec Bracelet en Silicone (1,40\")", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>59.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Smart 2.0 AMOLED Rose Gold Nude", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>99.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Ice Cartoon Shark - Montre Bleue pour Garçon avec Bracelet en Silicone - 018932 (Extra Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>39.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Smart 2.0 AMOLED Black", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>99.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE glam White - Montre blanche pour femme avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>62.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Solar Power Borealis - Montre Bleue pour Homme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 019032 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>69.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Digit Retro - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Plastique (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>62.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Flower Colour leaves - Montre Noire pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 020514 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>55.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Ice Glam Brushed Orchid - Montre Rose pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>55.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE lo White pink - Montre blanche pour femme avec bracelet en silicone - 013431 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>65.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE Digit - Montre pour Garçon avec Bracelet en Plastique", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>48.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE sixty nine Black - Montre noire mixte avec bracelet en silicone - 007277 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>69.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Solar Power Borealis - Montre Bleue pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 019033 (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>59.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - ICE Cosmos Crystal Numbers - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>68.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Ice Sunset Rainbow - Montre Blanche pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 015743 (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>78.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE sunset California - Montre blanche pour femme avec bracelet en silicone - 016049 (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>77.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Flower Twilight Daisy - Montre Bleue pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 019208 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>65.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Glam Rock Fame - Montre Noire pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 019859 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>99.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Digit Retro - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Plastique (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>52.0}
{  "title"=>"Smart Watch 022252", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>79.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Smart 2.0 AMOLED Silver", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>99.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - ICE glam brushed Clay - Montre rose pour femme avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>59.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - ICE glam brushed Fall rose - Montre rose pour femme avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>71.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE Cosmos - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH"}
{  "title"=>"ICE generation White forever - Montre blanche avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>69.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE sunsetBlack - Montre noire pour femme avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>79.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Flower - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone (Extra Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>55.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE glitter Black Rose-Gold - Montre noire pour femme avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>64.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Ice Solar Power - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>59.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Flower Poppy Fields - Montre Blanche pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 020512 (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>68.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - ICE blue White porcelain - Montre blanche pour femme avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>60.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Glitter Red Passion - Montre Rouge pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 021080 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>55.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch Damen-Uhren Analog Quarz 32020903", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>81.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE flower - Montre pour femme avec bracelet en silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>70.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Glitter Black - Montre Noire pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 001349 (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>89.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Ice Solar Power Navy Gold Mesh - Montre Bleue pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>69.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Digit - Montre Digitale pour Enfant avec Bracelet en Plastique (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>61.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Hero Aqua Fairy - Montre Verte pour Fille avec Bracelet en Silicone - 020327 (Extra Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>47.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Montre Enfant Bracelet Silicone Ola Kids (014431)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>46.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Solar Power Casual Brown - Montre Marron pour Homme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 020607 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>67.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Glam Brushed Sepia - Montre Marron pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 020546 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>62.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Flower - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone (Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>87.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Ice Solar Power White Gold - Montre Blanche pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>59.0}
{  "title"=>"ICE cartoon Dino - Montre bleue pour garçon avec bracelet en silicone - 018931 (Extra small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>56.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice-Watch - Ice Solar Power - Montre pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>61.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Glam Rock Rebel - Montre Blanche pour Femme avec Bracelet en Silicone - 019860 (Medium)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>49.0}
{  "title"=>"Ice Hero Yellow Spy - Montre Jaune pour Garçon (Mixte) avec Bracelet en Silicone - 020324 (Extra Small)", "brand"=>"ICE-WATCH", "price"=>44.0}
```